# Meteor AutoForm - validate on input change (keyup) and submit without using a form?

Tags: meteor

I'm using the Autoform + Simple-Schema + Collection2 packages for Meteor.

Unfortunately my form doesn't use a standard form pattern in that there aren't any form tags and no form submit button. Everything is done via jQuery and JS. Just input boxes and a button that uses jQuery to grab the values inside the input boxes when pressed.

I have my schema defined and I would like to use AutoForm to:

1. Validate against the schema on keyup of a form input field. (currently Autoform only validates when its Submit button is pressed).
2. Allow submission via my jQuery button method above.

Basically, it seems that AutoForm is tied to having to press a Submit button and having form tags for things to happen. I want to de-couple it from needing the Submit button and to be able to validate (and change the bootstrap form classes has-error / has-success on keyup).

The following code does not work. Just an example of where I'm at.

```
{{#autoForm collection="OrderSubmissions" id="orderSubmissionsForm" type="insert"}}

  <div class="col-md-12 {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='sqft'}}has-error{{/if}} "> <!-- if the below afFieldInput is invalid, it wraps the red has-error border around it - but where does it get the has-success? There's no else statement. -->
    <label>Square Footage of all Interior Spaces *</label>
    {{> afFieldInput name="sqft" id="sqft" class="form-control track-order-change track-initial-info-change"}}
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-6">
    {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name="sqft"}}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled>Checkout</button>
    {{else}}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
    {{/if}}
  </div>

{{/autoForm}}
```

***UPDATE***

Bah, nevermind. I read further down the documentation and apparently there is keyup validation.